# The Background Image for My Div Won't Show

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I can't get the background image of my `Container Div` to display. And the other thing is why is the border around my motorcycle picture so huge? Should it not be as close to the size of the picture contained as possible? I am totally baffled! Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> 
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Random Quote Machine.css">
</head>

<div class ="container">
    <div class="Motorcycle">
        <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
        <img src="https://s25.postimg.org/hxygqincv/Motorcycle_Helmet.jpg"> 
    </div>
</div>

<body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.container{
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("../https://s25.postimg.org/exhm9rejz/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1.jpg") no-repeat: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    /**border: 3px solid grey;**/
}

/**                     

}
**/

.Motorcycle{
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;*
    text-align: center;
}

/**
```

This is the output I currently have: [image: Snapshot]

Comment: Remove the `../` at the start of your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Css

```
background-image: url("../https://s25.postimg.org/exhm9rejz/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1.jpg") no-repeat: fixed;
```

to

```
background-image: url("https://s25.postimg.org/exhm9rejz/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1.jpg");
```

```css
.container{
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("https://s25.postimg.org/exhm9rejz/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    /**border: 3px solid grey;**/
    back
}

/**                     

}
**/

.Motorcycle{
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid grey;*
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> 
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Random Quote Machine.css">
</head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="Motorcycle">
        <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
        <img src="https://s25.postimg.org/hxygqincv/Motorcycle_Helmet.jpg"> 
    </div>
</div>

<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

background-image: url("img_tree.png");
remove from start of url "../".
https://s25.postimg.org/exhm9rejz/galaxy-s8_overview_kv_type1.jpg